Why does cooking meat with heat from all sides make such a big difference in taste?
I have this apparatus that you put in a whole bird's butt and it keeps the bird upright in the oven. I have tried cooking the same bird with the same spices and the same resting time. All the variables are the same, yet the bird that is cooked with heat from all sides is just simply superior.
You may find it hard that just the application of heat can make a difference in taste, but it seems to be the case. Why does the application of heat make such a difference in taste?

Could it possibly just be that this contraption is helping you not overcook the meat by allowing even application of heat on all sides and not requiring rotation/manipulation? (Or phrases otherwise; could it be that doing it the normal way you're overcooking parts of it when trying to get it cooked through on all sides?) Overcooked meat would be less juicy which would affect your perception of the taste.

There could be a real difference...or there could be a perceived difference.  A better place to start would be with identical birds treated the same way with the only variable being the cooking method.  In this experiment, you would of course need a thermometer to ensure the same done-ness.  Then, you could do a triangle test (with multiple people tasting) to blindly identify whether or not there indeed were the differences you think you have noticed.   At that point, one could ask the "why" question.

Assuming you've kept all the other variables the same in your other attempts, and based on your description, I'll list some of the things are actually happening to help achieve the difference you noticed.
Before we get into the physics of it, I'd like to define "simply superior" as a bird with more parts with more Maillard reaction and more even done-ness (save for the breast that could end up over cooked by the time the legs are cooked).

Your apparatus keeps the meat away from the dripping water/juice allowing that part and by conduction nearby parts to reach cooking temperature at the same time as the rest of the bird.  resting a side of the bird in its juices essentially buffers the bottom part from heat above boiling temperature (100°C/212°F) regardless of oven temp.
Your apparatus allows for more of the meat to receive convection heat by allowing the hot air (and IR) to reach all parts equally
By standing up the bird, your apparatus allows for the hot air to cook the insides and exist the top as opposed to get mostly trapped in the cavity.
By standing up the bird, you're somewhat liming the direct heat that would be otherwise applied to the breast, this helps keep it less over-cooked.

Therefore you have a bird that is cooking from the outside-in as well as inside-out all at nearly the same rate.
If you have a pastry drying rack, you can place the bird on that so it's lifted off the bottom of the pan and get almost the same results.
There is an engineering joke that in equations a cow is a sphere.  To put it crudely, your experiment is closer to heating the perfect sphere in space than the other methods.
Note-1: Rotisserie chickens are done in a similar way (not resting in their own juice and distributed heat)
Note-2: If you find the bird breast is still slightly overdone, you can stick an aluminum (aluminium) foil in the shape of a shield over it (toothpicks help) for the first 2/3 of the cooking time.
Note-3: By the same token, stuffing the bird is counter productive as it buffers the heat reaching the inside and slows the conduction cooking via keeping a colder core. Placing the stuffing under the bird to catch the juices may be an alternative.
